# Банкет и банкетка

Tags: этимология

Почему банкет это "торжественный званый обед или ужин", а банкетка "разновидность табурета"?

Comment: Банкет — Заимств. в XVII в. из нем. яз., где Bankett — из итал. banchetto «скамейка» (вокруг стола), уменьшит.-ласкат. образования от banco «скамья», см. банк, стол. Ср. стол «угощенье», накрывать стол, посиделки, др.-рус. беседа «скамья». Так что "банкетка" - скамейка, а банкет~стол.